# How perform search by key contains in kafka-ui?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, provectuslabs-kafka-ui

Documentation [provide exmaples](https://docs.kafka-ui.provectus.io/faq/faq#smart-filters-syntax). But when I try to use `keyAsText ~ ".*"` I got no results:

[image]

How to write correct regexp to search in kafka ui?

Answer (score 0):

The filter you’re applying in your screenshot is a quick search rather than a smart filter your syntax is intended for.
To solve this, click on “Add filters” and add one there.

Source: I’m the developer of the UI.